# UIView added with autolayout does not receive taps/events

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uigesturerecognizer

When I add a subview with autolayout by settings its left, right, top, and height constraints, I cannot add a tap gesture and my buttons do not receive taps.

When I manually set the frame to the position I need and do not use autolayout, I can add gesture recognizers and my buttons are interactive.

Why would a view added with autolayout not respond to events?

I would like to use autolayout since I would like to respond to different orientations and sizes that are more complex than I would like to deal with with manual frame adjustment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you have restricted your view too much using autolayout. For example, you may have accidentally set the height of the view to zero or positioned it outside the area where you put your buttons. Note that the buttons themselves can be positioned in a place that appears correct when you look at them, but they are actually outside the area that the autolayout engine has calculated for the parent view.

Another thing that can hit you, is that if you added all your autolayout contraints programmatically, some contraints in the Interface Builder may still be enabled. You can make sure that IB contraints are ignored by setting `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`

Also, pay attention to any runtime autolayout warnings in the console window, they will often tell you if some contraints don't play well together.

Comment: I SWEAR I did all of these. But I guess not.

1.) Make sure your autolayout constraints are right. My height constraint was NOT getting set, which is why the view appeared disabled and did not have the right background color.

You also need translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints -> NO on the subview being added.